# Bad on output of Constant-Current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, simulation, constant-current, proteus

#### What I'm trying to do?

I'm making a constant-current source based off an existing design. The specs of the existing design are:

#### Existing Design

The design is of a constant current source capable of outputting **4-20mA** output current from an input voltage of **0-2V**.

[image]

#### The Problem

The problem is when physically making the circuit, the output of this circuit is stuck at **56mA** irrespective of input.

I cannot find/contact the original author of the schematics to discuss the problem and its up to me to figure this out.

The simulations also show the same results as in reality:

[image]

[image]

### Simulation Findings

```
Input: Sinusoidal Wave of 0-2V peaks of frequency 1 per second
Output Current: Constant current of 56 mA
Output Voltage: 13.6474V with small ripples with amplitude in microvolts.
```

#### PMOSFET Info

[image]

```
V(Gate)   : 23V
V(Source) : 14V
V(GS)     : 8V
```

### Question

```
1) Where should I start looking for issues?
2) What is the name of the op-amp configuration being used in the second stage? I do know that the 
   first stage is a voltage follower.
```

[image]

#### EDIT 1: Resolving whether PMOSFET Symbol is correct

I have inverted the MOSFET just in case and the result is a little better but still not close to expected. Don't know whether inverted helped or made it worse.

[image]

Comment: The connection to the inverting input of U2A in your design does not match U4A in the old design.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks for spotting that. That error was already fixed by the time I ran the simulation so the results are still valid. Its just an old screenshot, I'll update it.

Comment: In the simulation, does the DC operating point make sense? Are all the op-amps working in their linear regions, and the FETs in saturation?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just a beginner and am currently googling to find out DC operating point of these op-amps. The FET is in saturation with Vgs of 8V (sorry if I'm wrong about this). See edit as well, the PMosfet section.

Comment: I think your PFET (Q2) is upside down.  The source should go to the positive supply side.

Comment: @Aaron, yes. Strange symbol on the original circuit, with the gate exactly in the middle.

Comment: @Aaron and vangelo I have inverted the mosfet and added results as Edit 1 at the end of post. Please check.

Comment: The original part (Q5) is drawn as a P channel JFET, which is an depletion mode device. But they are also using the same symbol type for the 2n7002, which is *not* a JFET.  The symbol for Q2 that you have is for an enhancement type MOSFET.

Comment: There's something strange going on with the P-MOS in your simulation. Your voltage notes show it with Vgs of at least -19V, but it's barely conducting. You have an an appropriate simulation model selected there?

Comment: I re-created your schematic in Circuit-Lab and it simulates fine there ...

Comment: @brhans can you please share simulation link please

Comment: @Mohsin could you please confirm that the original circuit is supposed to provide 4mA at the output when the input = 0V?

Comment: @vangelo I found this strange as well but the schematic states that it does. If you look close to output label

Comment: @Mohsin In the output yes, but where is the DAC range stated? To be more explicit: for a 0V input the output should also be zero (or very close to this).

Comment: I'd double check pins of devices to model. For example pin number doesn't match for 2N7002 and datasheet (might be ok). For Q2 symbol and label doesn't match; PMOS current should go source to drain [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/basic-p-type-mosfet-question#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=For%20an%20N%2DChannel%20MOSFET,switched%20from%20source%20to%20drain.)
Also for q2 I've heard voltage to current converter as a name, see [link](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/ElectroSim/Booster.html)

Comment: @Mohsin - posted as an answer because I can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to just post a link without creating a Circuit-Lab account.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit simulates fine in Circuit-Lab.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8UR7w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The comment from vangelo on your question is also applicable - for 0V in you cannot get 4mA out with this circuit.
It's not a 0-2V to 4-20mA converter, it's a 0-2V to **0**-20mA converter.

Answer (score 0):

The LED and the diode in series seem to give some headroom for the op. amp. since the original one can't reach V+ and that also applies to the inputs. Depending on the op. amp. you use, you may have problems.

If R10 was connected directly to +VF the input voltage of the third op. amp. would be very close to +VF (from +VF to +VF-2).

This is what you should expect for 1V DC input:

[image]